# Do “Clean Code”'s function argument number guidelines apply to API design?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am a newbie reading Uncle Bob's Clean Code Book.

It is indeed great practice to limit the number of function arguments as few as possible. But I still come across so many functions offered in many libraries that require a bunch of arguments. For example, in Python's pandas, there is a function with **9** arguments:

```py
DataFrame.groupby(by=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=<object object>, observed=False, dropna=True)
```

(And this function also violates the advice about flag arguments)

It seems that such cases are much rarer in Python standard libraries, but I still managed to find one with 4 arguments:

```py
re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
```

I understand that this is just a suggestion instead of silver bullet, but is it applicable when it comes to something mentioned above?

Comment: I think such a case in Python is more acceptable because of keyword arguments, which not all languages have. (Clean Code uses Java, which afaik does not have this feature.) While this doesn't mitigate all the downsides of having a many-argument function, it does make them easier to use - you usually don't have to specify more than a few of them, and you don't have to remember the order. I worked on a legacy PHP codebase a few years ago with many multi-argument functions where you had to count to figure out that the flag you needed to set was, say, the 9th argument - that was no fun at all!

Comment: Oh your statement about keyword arguments make sense to me, no wonder I feel totally comfortable as a user using `groupby`. So it seems the special advantage of Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncle Bob does not mention a hard limit of arguments that would make your code smell, but I would consider 9 arguments as too much.
Today's IDEs are much better in supporting the readability of the code, nevertheless refactoring stays tricky, especially with a large number of equally typed arguments.

The suggested solution is to encapsulate the arguments in a single struct/object (depending on your language). In the given case, this could be a GroupingStrategy:

```java
strategy = GroupingStrategy(); 
strategy.by = "Foo"
strategy.axis = 0
strategy.sorted = true

DataFrame.groupby(strategy)
```

All not mentioned attributes will be assigned with the respective default values.
You could then also convert it to a [fluent API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

```java
DataFrame.groupby(GroupingStrategy.by("Foo").axis(0).sorted())
```

Or keep some of the arguments, if this feels better:

```java
DataFrame.groupby("Foo", GroupingStrategy.default())
```

Comment: I knew that encapsulating trick before but it surprises me to covert it to a fluent API. It looks good but pandas developers seem to prefer the current way, is it because Python's mechanism about keyword arguments makes the current design acceptable? When it comes to other languages without kwargs like Java and C, would developers take some ways like what you introduce to avoid too many arguments in realworld API methods?

Comment: Developers sometimes tend to large parameter lists to show the possibilities of their functions. Some also want to be transparent regarding the defaults. And more than you think never heard of clean code.
Creating a fluent API is a lot of work, you don't get them out of the box. But meanwhile you can see them quite often in the Java ecosystem. Finally, code quality systems like SonareQube will mark large argument lists as code smell.

Comment: Copy that. It seems that standard of code quality varies a lot around programmers.

Comment: You got it. Today everybody can write code that runs/compiles. But writing code that is readable and maintainable (by others!) is a craftsmanship.

Answer (score 1):

The first point to note is that all those arguments to `groupby` are relevant. You can reduce the number of arguments by having different versions of `groupby` but that doesn't help much when the arguments can be applied independently of each other, as is the case here. The same logic would apply to `re.split`.

It's true that integer "flag" arguments can be dodgy from a maintenance point of view - what happens if you want to change a flag value in your code? You have to hunt through and manually fix each case. The traditional approach is to use `enum`s (which map numbers to words eg a `Day` enum would have Day.Sun = 0, Day.Mon = 1, etc) In compiled languages like C++ or C# this gives you the speed of using integers under the hood but the readability of using labels/words in your code. However `enum`s in Python are slow.

One rule that I think applies to any source code is to avoid "magic numbers", ie numbers which appear directly in the source code. The `enum` is one solution. Another solution is to have constant variables to represent different flag settings. Python sort-of supports constants (uppercase variable names in `constant.py` which you then import) however they are constant only by convention, you can actually change their value :(

Comment: Thx for your answer and it helps a lot with my understanding about flag arguments. As a user, I think that the design of `groupby` arguments is reasonable, but it seems bad for maintenance. Is it something like concession or tradeoff?

Comment: The `axis` argument is essentially an integer flag or `enum` {0 for ‘index’, 1 for ‘columns’}. It would be cleaner, as you say, to declare variables for these two possible values. For example in `constant.py` such as AXIS_INDEX=0 and AXIS_COLUMNS=1. At the top of your program `import constant` and then use AXIS_INDEX or AXIS_COLUMNS rather than 0 or 1.